# Saying "I know he is ..." without "I'm not sure"

Tags: word-choice

I want to say this about someone:

> "I know he is one of the winners." I'm not 100% sure , but some 80-90%".

If I say just *"I **know** he is one of the winners"*, that means *"I am **sure** that he is one of the winners"*. Right?

What verb should I use instead of **'know'**?

> "I **guess** he is...",
> "I **think** he is ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say that you are "fairly sure", "fairly certain", or "nearly certain" that he is one of the winners, or if you want a verb, you can use "I think" or "I believe", which both express some uncertainty.

Comment: I believe "**I believe**" fits.